# How to setup an ad-hoc network in Ubuntu using IPv6 address?

Tags: ip, ipv6, ad-hoc-network

Please guide me to setup an ad-hoc network setup between two ubuntu linux machines with the IPv6 protocol.

I believe this command will help me to configure an IPv6 address but what about the gateway configuration in ad-hoc network?

```
ifconfig eth0 inet6 add 2001:0db8:0:f101::1/64 # machine 1
ifconfig eth0 inet6 add 2001:0db8:0:f101::2/64 # machine 2
```

I'm bit confused about the gateway configuration.

Comment: If you have a single LAN then you don't need to do anything. All of the machines will create their own link-local IPv6 addresses and you can just begin using them.

Answer (score 0):

If by ad-hoc network you mean that you don't have your own allocation of global unicast addresses, and you only want to communicate among a small set of networks and not with the rest of the internet, then I recommend that you use RFC 4193 addresses.

RFC 4193 allow you to generate your own /48 for local communication. The method is as follows the first byte will be FD, the next five bytes are chosen at random. The randomness is important, because that's what ensures you won't run into addressing conflicts in the future.

For example a RFC 4193 prefix could be fdf2:5e8e:743d::/48.

Configuration of IPv6 addresses in Ubuntu can be done through `/etc/network/interfaces` just like IPv4. Here is an example:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto  eth0
iface eth0 inet static
  address   192.168.0.42
  broadcast 192.168.0.255
  netmask   255.255.255.0
  gateway   192.168.0.1

iface eth0 inet6 static
  address fdf2:5e8e:743d::42
  netmask 64
  gateway fdf2:5e8e:743d::1
```

Comment: Its not "choose" there is a formula to help ensure randomness

Comment: @JimB RFC 4193 requires those five bytes to be generated randomly. It does not require a specific algorithm to be used. There is a suggested algorithm, which is not a great PRNG. The only entropy sources used by the suggested algorithm are current time and a MAC address. It is better to use `urandom` if you have it, it provides better randomness than the suggested algorithm in RFC 4193.

Comment: With a 41-bit space the level of randomness really doesn't matter that much.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It is only 40 bits, and I agree it isn't a lot. Whether the quality of the randomness matters depends on the exact usage scenario. My point simply is, that I don't want my answer to mention the specific algorithm from RFC 4193, because it isn't great and the RFC allow you to use a better PRNG.